# IE11 ： javascript / jqueryで、cssの-ms-writing-modeの設定値を取得したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

ブラウザはIE11で、javascript/jqueryを用いて、cssの-ms-writing-modeの設定値(tb-lr)を取得したいのですが、

```html
$("#target").css("writing-mode") →　undifined　※Chromeでは取得可能
$("#target").css("-ms-writing-mode") →　undifined
```

では、取得結果がundifinedとなってしまい取得出来ません。
また、画面表示は-ms-writing-modeが適用されており、縦書きになっております。

取得方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

Comment: IE9以上のモードになってますか？

Comment: そのモードは、どちらで確認出来るでしょうか？

Comment: 動作モードについては、[このサイトの記事](http://furoshiki.hatenadiary.jp/entry/ie_documentmode)を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: リンク掲載を有難う御座います。ドキュメントモードはIE11(既定)が選択されております。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下で取得することが出来ました。

```html
$("#target")[0].currentStyle.writingMode
```